# Real-estate property data for USA

Tags: data-request, data.gov, real-estate

Any location or database that has real-estate property information for the USA?
Data items could include:

- Monthly rental rate
- Purchase price
- Financing options
- Purchaser income

Comment: please take a look at questions with the tag [tag:real-estate]

Answer (score 2):

The U.S. Census Bureau's American Community Survey has information on rental and purchase prices but it's aggregated at various levels.

You can get detailed parcel level information about prices paid for real estate from most county assessor's offices, but there is no state or nationwide source of this information, and the U.S. has IIRC 3000 counties.